# custom float entry for tkinter throwing attribute error upon deleting contents

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Why do I get a `DoubleVar has no attribute _report_exception` error when trying to define a custom tkinter entry widget that accepts only floats?

It happens when I delete the contents of the entry widget to enter a new floating point number

I've tried to follow the example taken from the documentation [here](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-entry-validate.htm) except for changing tk.StringVar() to tk.DoubleVar() they look to be identical..

example of using custom entry widget:

```
self.depth_label = tk.Label(self, text="Maximum Depth")
self.depth_label.grid(row=1, column = 1)
self.depth_entry = FloatEntry(self, default=255.0)
self.depth_entry.grid(row=1, column = 2)
```

custom entry class

```
class FloatEntry(tk.Entry):

    def __init__(self, master, default=0.0, **kwargs):

        tk.Entry.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.default = default
        self.value = self.default
        self.float = tk.DoubleVar()
        self.float.set(self.value)
        self.float.trace("w", self.__callback)
        self.config(textvariable=self.float)

    def __callback(self, *dummy):
        value = self.float.get()
        new_value = self.validate(value)
        if new_value is None:
            self.float.set(self.default)
        elif new_value != value:
            self.value = new_value
            self.float.set(self.new_value)
        else:
            self.value = value

    def validate(self, value):
        try:
            if value:
                value = float(value)
            return value
        except ValueError:
            return None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happens when you delete the last character in the entry. The entry value becomes an empty string, and because you've tied the `Entry` widget to a `DoubleVar`, tkinter will try to convert the value to a double and will fail since an empty string is not a valid floating point number.

There are at least a couple of solutions. One is to tie the `Entry` widget to a `StringVar`, You can then add code to handle the special case where the widget is empty.

Another solution is to use the built-in entry widget validation code that can prevent the widget from ever having a non-valid floating point value. There a lengthy answer on stackoverflow dealing with how to use the validation feature here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4140988/7432.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `validatecommand` to check the input from the entry and return values against that.

```
import tkinter

def validate(action, index, value_if_allowed,
                       prior_value, text, validation_type, trigger_type, widget_name):
    text = entry.get()
    if text in '0123456789':
        try:
            float(value_if_allowed)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False
    else:
        return False

window = tkinter.Tk()

entry = tkinter.Entry(window)
vcmd = (window.register(validate),'%d', '%i', '%P', '%s', '%S', '%v', '%V', '%W')

entry.configure(validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd)

entry.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This will not work. If the user enters the string "3.14" it will fail the test `if text in '0123456789'`. The function will thus return false. Also, when you call `entry.get()`, that will return the value before the edit. You have the right instincts to use `validatecommand`, but your implementation is critically flawed.